# How many times a round does a creature take damage from Force Shard?

Tags: dnd-4e, psionics

Force Shard does your charisma mod damage to anyone in its area. but here is an interesting line from the power in the Psionic Power book:

> An enemy can take this damage only once per turn.

Is this a misprint? It is also on the D&D Insider's Character Builder. This means that in a fight of, say, 5 party members and 5 enemies there would be 10 turns (each entity gets a turn on a round). So if a creature ends its turn next to the Shard it would take my Charisma mod times 10 before being able to move on its next turn. Since my CHA Mod is 3, that would be 30dmg over the course of the round. This seems kinda high for an at-will power.

So is this supposed to be every turn or every round?

Comment: That's certainly not a misprint, turn and round are used *very specifically* and mean very different things

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is supposed to be every turn. There are 10 turns in a round, but only 1 of them would be the **enemy's**.

> A round represents about 6 seconds in the game world. In a round, every combatant takes a turn. See also turn and once per round.

Force Shard:

> Any enemy that enters the shard’s space or *ends **its** turn* there takes force damage.

The wording says once per turn to limit the effect of forced movement.
Imagine you are a wizard able to slide an enemy 5 squares. Without this limitation you could slide the enemy in, and out, and in, and out and in, triggering the Charisma damage 3 times.

But yes, if you and your party have enough forced movement, and enough out of turn actions, you could make the enemy take 11 times Charisma damage. 10 for entering, 1 for ending the its turn there.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused with the wording of this answer, first you say only 1 turn is the enemy's (implying only 1 turn of dmg for him standing near the shard) but end with saying he would take 11times Charisma dmg (33 dmg over the course of a round in this example).

Comment: He can take 1 instance for ending his turn there. All you have to do is not let him move out of the square. You can also make him take the damage 5 more times, you and every ally can move him in and out and in your respecitve turns. You can add 5 more instances by using out of turn  actions in the enemy's turns to move him out and in.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I think I get it. He has to **ENTER** *or* **End HIS Turn** next to the Shard. Not end ANY turn next to it. This makes much more sense as far as balancing issues go for an At-Will power.

Comment: Note that the entry doesn't have to be voluntary.  The reason for the "once per turn" language is to keep you from ping-ponging the enemy in and out of the zone- there are a ton of powers that received this errata, because if, say, you could slide an enemy 6 squares, they'd be able to enter multiple times in one turn.